# Cannot boot up when Adaptec SCSI card is replaced

Tags: boot, initramfs, scsi, uuid, dracut

Current Fedora 19 installation is on an Adaptec 29320 and I am trying to 
temporarily replace it with an Adaptec 29160. The functionality of the cards is
very nearly the same except the replacement is U160. All the other drives, ID's and configurations remain the same. About half way through the boot process everything stops and I get dropped to a dracut prompt. It gives me the UUID's of two devices(disk partitions) it says it can't find. These are the partitions for swap and for the root file system. Using a different SCSI controller seems to create a different UUID that doesn't match what's in the initramfs. It appears that the dracut prompt is giving me the opportunity to create a new initramfs right on the spot that will allow the boot process to continue. But I would need to know what parameters/options etc to give it. I went back into my installation and regenerated the grub.cfg using the variable GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true. The new grub.cfg now has root=/dev/sdc2. But this only gets me a little further in the boot process.

Answer (score 1):

A RAID controller cannot change the uuids of your partitions. It can, however, change the way in which RAID devices are constructed; that is, what they use as on-disk format, how disks are synced between each other, etc. Even controllers from the same brand are not at all guaranteed to use the same on-disk format.

If you're booting from the RAID, but then things fail after loading the kernel etc, then that would appear to mean that either the new RAID controller used a similar (but not identical) on-disk format, or (far less likely) that loading the driver and initializing the hardware changes the mode in which the controller works, causing it to look at the disks in a different way. Either way, you clearly cannot use the array created with one controller after switching controllers.

It you do want to do so, the only way is to put in the old controller, back up your data, swap controllers, reinstall, restore your data.

Comment: These aren't RAID controllers, they're just plain SCSI HBAs.

Comment: @WouterVerhelst  Actually, both of these cards have a certain amount of RAID capability that is available as an option.  It's something that I have never used and I believe most of the time I have deactivated it by turning it off in the SCSI BIOS settings.  I know it's been turned off on the 29320 since before the Linux installation.  It's been a while since I have used the 29160. When I installed it, I didn't think to go into the SCSI BIOS and check all the settings.

Comment: Maybe double-check that you have switched it off, then?